# Angular 5: BehaviourSubject for multiple email field validation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I work on Angular5, my project page has an upload functionality in which for which I will be using a `core` upload component from my own organization. The user can upload 5 files and before clicking the `upload` button user has to fill in the email field.

My requirement is as soon as the user focus out of the `email` field a service call will be made and on the bases of the service response I will show the error message.

I am doing this like below:

My Component HTML

```
<my-upload-compt (validateEmail)="checkEmail($event)" [isEmailValid]="isEmailValid"></my-upload-compt>
```

My Component TS

```
isEmailValid: BehaviourSubject<boolean>;

checkEmail($event){
    // make service call, suppose the service returns false.
    this.isEmailValid.next(false);
}
```

Core Component TS

```
@Input() isEmailValid: BehaviourSubject<boolean>

ngOnInit(){
    this.isEmailValid.subscribe(value => {
    // show error msg
});
}
```

My problem is, if I enter a valid email in 1st field and an invalid email in next field, even the first field shows the error message. How to show error message for the particular field as soon the focus out is done? Please guide.

PS: function call on focus out is working fine its just that all the fields start showing error even if 1 field has wrong email

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for Angular [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and [AsyncValidatorFn](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidatorFn).
By using this you will be able to implement the desired behavior per field.